# Can I use "$\iff$" symbol when I "transform" an expression to another form?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am writing a solution to prove that $\sqrt5$ is not rational. Here is my first half proof:

> Assume $\sqrt{5}$ is a rational number. By the definition of rational number, $\sqrt{5} = \frac{p}{q}$, where $p,q\in\mathbb{Z^+}, q\neq0$, and $gcd(p,q)=1$. We have $5=\frac{p^2}{q^2} \iff 5q^2=p^2$.

Can I use "$\iff$" symbol like this?

---

How about if a question is asking me to work backward from the desired conclusion and then prove:

If x and y are nonnegative integer, then $\frac{x+y}{2}\geq \sqrt{xy}$.

Can I do like something like:

> (first half proof) $\frac{x+y}{2}\geq \sqrt{xy} \iff x+y\geq 2\sqrt{xy} \iff (x+y)^2 \geq 4xy 
> \iff x^2+2xy+y^2 \geq 4xy \iff x^2-2xy+y^2 \geq 0 \iff (x-y)^2 \geq 0$.

Should I use $\iff$, $\Leftarrow$ or $\Rightarrow$?

Comment: If $p,q\in\mathbb Z^+$, then certainly $q\neq 0$, so you don't need to write that $q\neq 0$.

Comment: @user236182 hmm, my textbook says "[...] where p and q are positive integers, $q\neq0$", is that redundant also? Thanks!

Comment: Some people think that it’s more mathematical to use fewer words and more symbols. In some cases this is true, especially when the words are long and repetitive. Mostly, however, the words are fine, and my own feeling is that in formal mathematical writing it is improper to simply replace the word “then” within a paragraph with the symbol “$\Rightarrow$”.

Comment: Thank you! @Lubin. How about in the second case I mentioned above, is it appreciate to use $\iff$?

Comment: @lawrenceli9308 It's redundant too. If $p,q>0$, then this already implies that $q\neq 0$.

Comment: To answer your question, my own style would be to start with the true fact $(x-y)^2\ge0$ and proceed through most of your steps to the desired $(x+y)/2\ge\sqrt{xy}$, using words to connect the inequalities, perhaps even saying, “we get, successively   ” following these words with several of your conclusions. Or maybe I would make a display, in which situation the arrows (pointing right) would seem appropriate to me. By the way, an argument of the form $a\Rightarrow b\Rightarrow c\Rightarrow d$ etc., is called a sorites (three syllables).

Comment: @Lubin That's what I did :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. "$\iff$" is used to denote *logical equivalence*, or *necessary and sufficient conditions*. It is read "if and only if," of which "iff" is a common abbreviation. $p \iff q$ is true if $p$ is true whenever $q$ is true *and* $q$ is true whenever $p$ is.

> Assume $\sqrt{5}$ is a rational number. By the definition of rational number, $\sqrt{5} = \frac{p}{q}$, where $p,q\in\mathbb{Z^+}, q\neq0$, and $gcd(p,q)=1$. We have $5=\frac{p^2}{q^2} \iff 5q^2=p^2$.

This is true, since $5=\frac{p^2}{q^2} \Rightarrow 5q^2=p^2$ and $5q^2=p^2 \Rightarrow 5=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$.

> If x and y are nonnegative integer, then $\frac{x+y}{2}\geq \sqrt{xy}$.
>
> **Proof:** $\frac{x+y}{2}\geq \sqrt{xy} \iff x+y\geq 2\sqrt{xy} \iff (x+y)^2 \geq 4xy 
> \iff x^2+2xy+y^2 \geq 4xy \iff x^2-2xy+y^2 \geq 0 \iff (x-y)^2 \geq 0.$

This is a fine proof. I would like to see it start where you end, but with $\iff$ used as you do here, it's perfectly valid as is.

Comment: the only thing to add is that you might want to note (for yourself if not for your reader) where the equivalence is guaranteed by one of your auxiliary conditions (e.g. in the first proof, implicitly we need $q\neq 0$ or the whole thing falls apart; in the latter, when we square everything, we need that both sides are positive, which is in turn guaranteed by the restrictions on $x,y$) as opposed to being true in general

Comment: @MichaelChirico Of course. My answer is meant to comment on the use of the symbol. In the proof I quote, I take the OP's hypotheses for granted- I mean just to consider his use of the symbol in question, not present a proof myself. He's already done that.

Answer (score -1):

You are moving forward in the proof, so you can use $\implies$ (this implies) sign which is more appropriate.

Comment: $\iff$ is also appropriate. In this case, $\implies$ is enough, because it's a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @user236182 Thanks! Because my professor wrote sth like: Then $5=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$, so $5q^2=p^2$. I was just wondering if I could use arrows instead of writing "then","so","thus", etc.

Comment: @lawrenceli9308 "then", "so", "thus" are all equivalent to $\implies$. Here you can also use $\iff$, which means "if and only if", "is equivalent to".